# problem in echoing 8 bytes in STM32 SPI slave

Tags: stm32, c, spi

Linux SPI master sends 8 bytes data of these every 1 second:

```
using packet_t = std::array<std::uint8_t, PACKET_LENGTH>;
            static packet_t data[] = {
                {0xff, 0x00, 0xff, 0x00, 0xff, 0x00, 0xff, 0x00},
                {0xf0, 0xf0, 0xf0, 0xf0, 0xf0, 0xf0, 0xf0, 0xf0},
                {0xcc, 0xcc, 0xcc, 0xcc, 0xcc, 0xcc, 0xcc, 0xcc},
            };
```

The clock rate is 500kHz.

STM32 SPI slave can receive these data correctly. It tries to echo the received data.
But it can only send last 4 bytes in the next master transmission. The rest first 4 bytes can be sent in the 2 steps later in master transmission. I have checked MISO line by the scope. STM32 slave sends the wrong data. So the master sees these:

```
<1st TXRX>
TX ff 00 ff 00 ff 00 ff 00
RX f0 f0 f0 f0 cc cc cc cc

<2nd TXRX>
TX f0 f0 f0 f0 f0 f0 f0 f0
RX cc cc cc cc ff 00 ff 00

<3rd TXRX>
TX cc cc cc cc cc cc cc cc
RX ff 00 ff 00 f0 f0 f0 f0

<4th TXRX>
TX ff 00 ff 00 ff 00 ff 00
RX f0 f0 f0 f0 cc cc cc cc
```

The code of callback is here:

```
#define PACKET_LENGTH 8
uint8_t miso_data[PACKET_LENGTH];
uint8_t mosi_data[PACKET_LENGTH];

void HAL_SPI_TxRxCpltCallback(SPI_HandleTypeDef * hspi)
{
    HAL_StatusTypeDef retStatus;
    if (hspi == m_hspi_nx)
    {
        ...

        retStatus = HAL_SPI_TransmitReceive_IT(m_hspi_nx, miso_data, mosi_data, PACKET_LENGTH);
        ...
        osSemaphoreRelease(*m_sem_nx_rx);
    }
}
```

I am using STM32F767.

[Edit]
If I don't use the interrupt, it works fine.

```
HAL_SPI_TransmitReceive(m_hspi_nx, miso_data, mosi_tmp_data, PACKET_LENGTH, HAL_MAX_DELAY);
```

But I need to use the interrupt.

Comment: `osSemaphoreRelease(*m_sem_nx_rx);` looks fishy, where exactly do you set/release this? If you set it in main() and do for example some slow buffer copy, that might disrupt the SPI interrupt.

Comment: Are you certain that you've configured the callback function(s) correctly? It looks like you might be getting a "Half-Complete" callback instead of the "Complete" callback you're expecting.

Answer (score 0):

The reason I had this problem is that I used RX buffer in SPI slave.
I think SPI slave don't need RX buffer because its RX and TX are done simultaneously. Sorry for this ugly question.